# Authenticate MVC Contoller Using Bearer Token and redirect to the Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I Have created a MVC Controller, Please find the below code

Now i got a requirement to create with OAuth

I have created Client Id, Client Secret, Resource and Secrect Key in Azure, 
and using that i can able to get Bearer Token

Now Could any one help me to Authenticate in My MVC controller and redirect to bankCreationController using c#

```
public class BankCreationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/BankCreationController ")]
    public string BankCreationController (sting s)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Authenticatrion happens using ASP.NET's authentication system which runs before Controllers. Use the `[Authorize]` attribute and set-up the authentication and authorization pipeline in your `Startup.cs`. Is this ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? And if it's Core, is it Core 1 or Core 2? The AuthX system was changed significantly in Core 2.

Answer (score 3):

I got a chance to setup a Bearer Authentication with .Net MVC 5, and here is how I set up it using a custom attribute. I think we need to customize a little to make it work for .Net Core

The api needs to have an annotation, in this case I named it BearerAuthentication, so that it will check the header of the request for the bearer authentication before it can reach inside the method of BankCreationMethod

```
[HttpPost]
[BearerAuthentication]
[Route("someurl")]
public string BankCreationMethod(string s){
}
```

Then create a custom attribute class name BearerAuthentication, inherits from ActionFilterAttribute. Every request to the actions that have annotation [BearerAuthentication] will be checked by this method OnActionExecuting. If the header of the request is Bearer type and has a valid token, this will return a valid result, otherwise will be a HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized response to the action.

```
public class BearerAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {

        // 1. Look for credentials in the request.
        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        // 2. If there are no credentials, do nothing.
        if (authorization == null)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;
        }

        // 3. If there are credentials but the filter does not recognize the 
        //    authentication scheme, do nothing.
        if (authorization.Scheme != "Bearer")
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;
        }

        //4.If there are credentials that the filter understands, try to validate them.          
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            var apiKey = string.Empty;               
            if (!TokenService.IsValidToken(authorization.Parameter))
            {
                context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return;
            }

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

The service to check if the token from the request is valid and the algorithm to encrypt the token could be something this way with methods GenerateToken() and IsValidToken(string). The algorithm in this example is not like the Bearer token you generate from Azure but you can customize it somehow to match your case:

```
public static class TokenService
{
    public static int expireTime = 20;
    public static string GenerateToken()
    {
        byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
        var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var salt = "somesalt";          
        byte[] securedKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key + salt);
        string token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(securedKey).ToArray());
        return token;
    }

    public static bool IsValidToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
            //default expire time is 20 mins

            DateTime when = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));
            if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-expireTime))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Exception("Unauthorized!");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in the Startup.cs file, setup the AuthenticationTokenProvider (in this example is Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure) so that the app understand the method GenerateToken() from the TokenService above

```
public class Startup
{      
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AuthenticationTokenProvider authTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider();
        authTokenProvider.OnCreate = (context) =>
        {               
            context.SetToken(TokenService.GenerateToken());
        };

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,                              
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TokenService.expireTime),
            AccessTokenProvider = authTokenProvider,
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = authTokenProvider
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);            
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't seem to find out anything on SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider. Can someone help with that?