# Session and Token With Each Request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, token

I developed a project using `ASP.NET MVC` that uses session to keep track of users after login. Simply authorization! So I used the below code to use it as attribute in required controllers:

```
public class GppAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["userId"] == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Auth/Login");
    }
}
```

Finally in controller, doing this:

```
 [GppAuthorize]
 // GET: Dashboard
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

So for above, the scenario works fine. Now I am trying to validate each request with a token for authentication (Checks if the request has valid token to work with server-side) and not sure how to do that in `ASP.NET MVC 5` as most of the tutorials uses Web Api. I did few R & D and got this for a basic idea to start. Here is the link with an answer:

[Authenticate MVC Controller Using Bearer Token and Redirect To The Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326709/authenticate-mvc-contoller-using-bearer-token-and-redirect-to-the-controller)

It looks promising, the questions are: After login,

1. How can I create the token and pass it in each http request specifically after user login?
2. Is there anything that I require to do with session or it should be independent of session
   anyway?
3. If the example code with provided link works, how can I make it work for http request with
   `Ajax` call? Say for below code sample:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Dashboard/GetProducts",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (value) {
       alert(value);

       GetProjectDetails();
     },
     error: function (ex) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex); //Check if authentication failed here
     }
   ```

   });
4. Will this help me to prevent unauthorized url to access data from the website or web project
   that I am working with (Though I know, it'll but is there any way to override and make
   unauthorized url calls)?

Comment: A few questions: why do you not use the default `[Authorize]` attribute rather than your own? When you say "session" do you mean "cookie-based session"? What's the reason you want to use token-based sessions instead?

Comment: Yes, that's cookie-based session. My plan is to validate http request with token, so I was planning if that example could help. I am not sure if `[Authorize]` could help but if that can, I am happy to use it and you can point out how I can make it work with example or any tutorial link.

Comment: But **why** use tokens? If you have a purely MVC based project and no Web API, you're only making it more complicated for yourself using tokens because browsers use and understand cookies by default.

Comment: Just one thing to clear as I am novice in this field. I was thinking to make it more secure with token for each request (Clear me if I am wrong). Though for web api, we do use token, so what if we try to use it in MVC project.

Comment: One is not more secure than the other. It's just two different ways of exchanging information. Unless you have a specific reason for not wanting to use cookies in your current setup, I wouldn't change it.